# VPS Puppeteer Err

Tags: discord.js, puppeteer

I am having issues with running my bot with DigitalOverflow. It contains a command that takes a screenshots of websites and sends them in the channel. However, when I use the command with DigitalOverflow, I simply get this error, and I'm not sure how to fix it. There's nothing above that either and I've searched and searched with no avail.

```
        if(!message.channel.nsfw) return message.channel.send('This command is only usable in NSFW channels.')

    if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Please provide a URL!");
    let msg = args.join(" ")

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-gpu','--no-first-run','--no-sandbox',]});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    message.channel.send("Please wait, this may take a while.").then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 8000, reason: ""}))

    await page.goto(`${msg}`);

    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

    await browser.close();


  message.channel.send("`" + `${msg}` + "`", {files: ["./example.png"]}).catch((e) => message.channel.send(`Issue found: ${e}`))
```

[image]

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: @GillesQuenot, I would but it's inside of the DigitalOcean cmd prompt and the error only appears inside of DigitalOcean. (No they don't let me copy the output.)

Comment: Are you sure isn't DigitalOcean uses **some IP block,** like in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091884/puppeteer-doesnt-work-at-vps-digitalocean ?  It is a best practice to wrap promise dependent code in **try-catch** blocks, so if there is such error (e.g.: IP block on VPS) your app won't fail and you will have more specific error msg as well.